# What is the difference between CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT and CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT?

Tags: java, timeout, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

Could someone explain me the difference between these two parameters?

1. [org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/CoreConnectionPNames.html#CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
2. [org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/CoreConnectionPNames.html#SO_TIMEOUT).

According to the javadocs:

CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT:

> Determines the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is
>   established. A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite
>   timeout.

CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT:

> Defines the socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) in milliseconds, which is the
>   timeout for waiting for data or, put differently, a maximum period
>   inactivity between two consecutive data packets).

So, for the first one, `CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT`, does it happen before any data is sent?
And for the second, `CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT`, does it mean that some data was already sent? Meaning that connection was successfully established.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does it happen before any data is sent?

Yes, it does.

> does it mean that some data was already sent?

On HTTP level level, no, it does not. (TCP/IP or SSL may be a different story)

> Meaning that connection was successfully established.

Yes, it does.